# Difficulty defining interrupt in PIC18F14K50

Tags: pic, interrupts

When I try to set the interrupt on change in PIC18F14K50, I can't get the interrupt to run once and turn off the flag. What could be the problem in working with this component?

I am working with the mikroC compiler.

Interrupt routine:

```c
unsigned short cnt, mode, cycles; // counter, 2modes (8.3Hz, 20Hz)

void interrupt() {
  if (TMR2IF_bit) {
    // TMR2 = 0 Timer2 initial value by defalt
    if (cnt == cycles) {
      LATC.F0 = !LATC.F0;
      cnt = 0; // cnt initial value
    }
    cnt++; // increment counter
  }

  if (RABIF_bit) {
    mode = !mode; // Toggle mode
    if (mode) { // 8.3Hz mode1
      PR2 = 78;
      cycles = 96;
    }
    if (!mode) { // 20Hz mode0
      PR2=44;
      cycles=70;
    }
  }

  TMR2IF_bit = 0; // clear TMR0IF
  RB7_bit = 0; // for mismatch condition
  RABIF_bit = 0; // clear RABIF
}

void main() {
  TRISC.F0 = 0; // PORTC is output
  TRISB.F7 = 1; // interrupt input
  RABIE_bit = 1; // enable interrupt on change
  IOCB7_bit = 1; // enable interrupt on change RB5
  ANSEL = ANSELH = 0; // dig input only

  //timer2
  INTCON = 0b11000000; // Enable GIE PIE
  TMR2IE_bit = 1; // Enable TMR2 interrupt
  // (1/8.3)/2 = 0.5*10e-6*16*(pr2)(cnt) -> pr2=78 , cycles=96 (eror = 0.72%)
  // (1/20)/2 = 0.5*10e-6*16*(pr2)(cnt) -> pr2=44 , cycles=70 (eror = 1.44%)
  PR2 = 78;
  cycles = 96;
  T2CON = 0b00000110;; // postscale 1:1 TMR2ON prescaler 1:16 (1:16)
  Delay_ms(10);

  // I.C
  RC0_bit = 0; // I.C FOR RC0
  TMR2 = 0; // Timer2 initial value
  cnt = 0; // Initialize cnt
  mode = 1; // start from mode1
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why not just fill two arrays and index into them with the value of mode to set PR2 and cycles?  There's no need for any decision statement (let alone 2 decision statement).  Not a big deal, but keeping your interrupts sleek is a habit worth developing.

Comment: This is a task that demonstrates the use of interrupt. It didn't really matter what was written inside. I just want to activate it
but thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what error you're getting.  Is the interrupt running more than once, and you only want it to run once, or is it not running at all?  Can you show this with a minimal main() so we don't have to ask silly questions like "do you enable global interrupts?"

Comment: I updated the full program, it outputs a square wave at two different frequencies that change by pressing an external button

Comment: Don't you need to enable the external interrupt and not the peripheral interrupt??  Again-- you haven't told us whether your interrupt runs *at all*, or more than once.

Comment: On embedded systems you should never exit the `main` function. Near the end you have to add an infinite loop (`while (1) {}`) in order to prevent the `main` function from terminating.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done PIC programming in years but from what I can remember the interrupt flag is always active, you can not disable it.  What you can disable is the actual interrupt enable bit for the interrupt you want.  In your code for the interrupt service routine check for the interrupt being enable **and** the interrupt flag being set. Also ... don't clear the interrupt flags outside the interrupt block for that interrupt like you show at the end. The code below show **TMR2IE_bit** and **RABIE_bit**. **These register names are made up** because I'm not familiar with you compiler. You need to find the correct names and replace them.
**@velvet** commented that you are exiting the main function. He/She is correct. Take care of that as well.
Hope that helps.

```
void interrupt() 
{
    if (TMR2IF_bit && TMR2IE_bit)    
    {
       ...    

       TMR2IF_bit = 0; //clear TMR0IF 
       //TMR2IE_bit = 0; //disable this interrupt as needed
    }
    
    if (RABIF_bit && RABIE_bit)
    {
       ...

       RABIF_bit = 0; //clear RABIF
       //RABIE_bit = 0;  //disable this interrupt as needed
    }

    //Move this line below to one of 
    //the blocks above or it will
    //excecute on every interrupt
    //RB7_bit = 0; // for mismatch condition
}
```